# How to delete all content inside linear layout in android, entirely?

Tags: android, layout

please accept my  sincerest, for below question:
i've only begun to learn...(◕‿◕✿)
I attempt to redevelop a source code, but i have a problem in layouts, there are many code to "disable, visibility" children of a layout, but No  Guidance for delete content of a layout, entirely. for example;
i attempt to delete "profile layout", The layout is define in "layout folder" in source code path, name of the layout is "activity-profile.xml", for delete its , what should we do?
Im a beginner Miss, sorry, please step by step, thank you very much ☔ ☕...

Comment: Honestly I didn't get what you want to do.. I suggest you to start with some tutorials; [TheNewBoston's one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAbQgLGKd3Y) is honestly really good and complete. I suggest you to watch them and then try again :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all set id to parent view.

then do this below code :- 
Suppose your parent layout is Linearlayout then -

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = findviewById(R.id.linearLayout);
if(((LinearLayout) linearLayout).getChildCount() > 0)
 { 
   ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).removeAllViews(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
  LinearLayout linearlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myid);
  linearlayout.removeAllViews();
```